# Is there a way to scrape a non scrape-able website other than using BeautifulSoup and Scrapy as these aren't working?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the nbn plans from [Tangerine website](https://www.tangerinetelecom.com.au/nbn/nbn-broadband) as a scraping practice. I'm using BeautifulSoup and I'm able to scrape the data and see the scraped data in the terminal but once I save the data into a csv file, it doesn't work and I get some kind of weird typing.

I used BeautifulSoup but I also know how to use scrapy and used it before. I just want to know if it's possible to scrape the data and save it into a csv file using scrapy before I try and if it's not, what else can I use?

There's also some sites that I tried to scrape using scrapy but it wasn't working. I know that there's nothing wrong with my code because I tried scraping other sites and it worked.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas


url = requests.get('https://www.tangerinetelecom.com.au/nbn/nbn-broadband')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

plans = soup.find_all('div', class_="large-3 columns text-center")

data = []

for plan in plans:
    d = {}
    info = plan.find_all('p')
    title = info[0].text
    speed = info[1].text[0:-2]
    d['Speed'] = title + '\n' + speed
    d['Data'] = info[2].text
    d['Trial'] = info[3].text
    d['Contract'] = info[4].text
    d['Setup Fee'] = info[5].text
    d['Promo Price'] = info[6].text
    d['Price'] = info[7].text[0:-1]
    d['Price Details'] = info[8].text.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')

    data.append(d)

print(data)
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("tangerine.csv")
```

The expected result would be this data in a csv file:

```
[ {'Speed': 'Basic Speed \n10Mbps Typical Evening Speed ', 'Data': 'UNLIMITED DATA', 'Trial': 'RISK FREE TRIAL', 'Contract': 'NO CONTRACT', 'Setup Fee': '$0 SETUP FEE', 'Promo Price': 'SPECIAL PROMO PRICE', 'Price': '$49.90/mth', 'Price Details': '$49.90 for 6 months, then $59.90 ongoing'}, 
{'Speed': 'Speed Boost \n21Mbps Typical Evening Speed ', 'Data': 'UNLIMITED DATA', 'Trial': 'RISK FREE TRIAL', 'Contract': 'NO CONTRACT', 'Setup Fee': '$0 SETUP FEE', 'Promo Price': 'SPECIAL PROMO PRICE', 'Price': '$58.90/mth', 'Price Details': '$58.90 for 6 months, then $68.90 ongoing'}, 
{'Speed': 'XL Speed Boost \n42Mbps Typical Evening Speed ', 'Data': 'UNLIMITED DATA', 'Trial': 'RISK FREE TRIAL', 'Contract': 'NO CONTRACT', 'Setup Fee': '$0 SETUP FEE', 'Promo Price': 'SPECIAL PROMO PRICE', 'Price': '$64.90/mth', 'Price Details': '64.90 for 6 months, then $74.90 ongoing'}, 
{'Speed': "XXL Speed B'st \n83Mbps Typical Evening Speed ", 'Data': 'UNLIMITED DATA', 'Trial': 'RISK FREE TRIAL', 'Contract': 'NO CONTRACT', 'Setup Fee': '$0 SETUP FEE', 'Promo Price': 'SPECIAL PROMO PRICE', 'Price': '$69.90/mth', 'Price Details': '$69.90 for 6 months, then $79.90 ongoing'} ]
```

But I get some kind of a weird typing in the csv file instead:
[image: Image of the weird typing, I've been getting]

Comment: Can you share what the weird typing is? Chances are is just an encoding issue

Comment: _But I get some kind of a weird typing in the csv file instead_ If you showed this to us, maybe we could tell you why it is happening.

Comment: Sure, I just added a link to an image of the weird typing as I can't add the typing itself to the post.

Comment: Could not recreate issue.

Comment: maybe it's a setting in LibreOffice or similar

Comment: @LanteDellarovere I think that is the case. Can you tell us your encoding for libra? Does it accept csv files?

Comment: Yeah, it was the case and now it's working. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not the code but the encoding of your libra file.

Use these steps to change the encoding from `UTF-16` to `UTF-8`:

`File > New > Spreadsheet`, then `Insert > Sheet from file`. Choose your file and `OK`. You should get the text import window. At the top, check the "Character set" setting -- my guess is that it's not set properly. If it's not already, change it to `UTF-8`.

Comment: First, I just wanna say that I really appreciate the help. Thank you so much!
Second, I added ```import requests``` too but I missed it when I was copying the code and it's not working.
You used print(df) but I want it to be saved in a csv file.
It works fine in the terminal but it doesn't in the csv file.

Comment: Did the fix above work? I'm pretty sure the issue is that Libra is not in utf-8. I used print to make sure that the request wasn't pulling Chinese characters from the site.

Comment: This is why it is important to post all data when posting questions on Stack overflow. I would not have been able to solve it without a sample of the libra file.